# Advanced filtering in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

How can one create advanced filters in sails.js like the one in angular custom filters that can be combined with pagination?
I have tried using find(), but only was able to use where modifiers. I have to perform matching with values in another tables. Is there a way to use custom function as a criteria in the find()?

Comment: We need more information in order to answer this. I'm not sure what you mean by "perform matching with values in another table". Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to find instances of a model where some of its attributes match the attributes of another model, you can just do a nested find:

```
Model1.find({ attr1: filter1, ... }, function (err, firstModels {
  firstModels.forEach(function (firstModel) {
    Model2.find({ someAttr: firstModel.attr1, ... }, function (err, secondModels) {
      // do what you need to do with what you find (i.e. store in an outside list, etc)
    });  
  });
});
```

You mentioned pagination, which you can do with the `skip()` or `paginate()` functions; you can even run your own custom queries with the `query()` function, or use some more [built-in advanced features](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md). See the [Waterline documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query.md) for more information.